# Looping through a list to pass as argument in function Python

Tags: python, dictionary, overriding, args

So I have a class **DictList** that has an args parameter which takes in dictionaries and appends them into a list. My professor wants me to to override the addition function in Python to add 2 DictLists together (both refer to a list of dictionaries). The problem I'm having right now is returning a new DictList after adding 2 DictLists together.

I can extend both their lists together, but I'm not quite sure how to create a new DictList with the data I have since it's in a list. I was thinking about iterating through the list and passing each dictionary into the DictList, but ... I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DictList(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args
    def __add__(self, other):
        return DictList(self.args + other.args)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = DictList( (dict(a=1), dict(b=2)) )
>>> b = DictList( (dict(c=3), dict(d=4)) )
>>> c = a + b
>>> c.args
({'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 3}, {'d': 4})
```